# Как сделать событие на нажатие в гугл карте?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

На карте есть сгруппированные метки (Marker Cluster), нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на метки внутри них срабатывало событие (Запуск функции) для отправки взятых данных в форму заявки, для того чтобы далее отправить запрос в базу данных. Не могу понять, как сделать в данном примере слушатель события на клик.

```js
   function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
          
        });
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
      
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length],
            title: 'Click to zoom'
          });
        });
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
    
      var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]
    function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
      var lat = latlng.lat();
      var lng = latlng.lng();
 
      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng;
      GDownloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Данные добавлены.";
        }
      });
    }
```

```css
#map {
width: 100%; height: 400px; padding: 0; margin: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAFejP9B-T5JwSNtNMjVKCUfjPD0TMTI2I&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Ну есть кто знает? Уже день мучаюсь, не могу до конца настроить эту штуку:(

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет про `markerCluster`, то

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Не на сам кластер а на метки в нем (Красные).